# What are some projects I can build on Amazon AWS to build my skills?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have recently been messing around with Amazon AWS, mainly EC2 and S3. I have some experience with the services AWS has to offer but I would like to expand on that. I have successfully implemented S3 on to a website I run and set up a LAMP stack on Ubuntu using the free teir. I know AWS has a lot more to offer so what would be some ideal projects/scenarios I could set up?

Comment: This question is really vague and can't really be answered. There are tons of things you *could* do, but we don't know what you're interested in, what your business is, what your goals are...

Comment: That's what I am looking for, a list of things I COULD do. i.e. setting up a load balancer. My goal I suppose is to learn more about Windows Server and Linux. Since before a service like this you would literally have to invest in the software licenses, server hardware and networking gear to be able to "play" around with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting up several load balanced web servers using either/or a *nix based load balancer like HAproxy, or Amazon's Elastic Load Balancer. These web servers could also have alternative backends, MySQL or try Amazon's Relational Database Service. You could also group these servers into web & app servers as well as database and segment each with Amazon VPC.

You could swap out your DNS for Amazon's Route 53...

You could use Amazon CloudFront as a content delivery network for your site(s).

LOTS to do! :)
http://aws.amazon.com/ << click products